# OSPF inter-area traffic - not so direct after all

Tags: routing, router, ospf

a) Can I confirm inter-area traffic will be routed towards Area 0 / Area 0 will be the transit network for all inter-area traffic?

b) Consider the diagram below

[image]
q1) Does R1 receive Type 3 LSA for Area 3 via both Area 1 and Area 0 from R2 ?

q2) Going by the rule above that all inter-area traffic must transit Area 0, isn't it totally not efficient for traffic from Area 2 <-> Area 3 to pass through Area 0 via a 100 Mbs link, when Area 2 can reach Area 3 through Area 1 on 1 Gbps link?

q3) How does/will traffic from Area1 go to Area2 ? All inter-area traffic must go through Area0... but.. how ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The goal of the area 0 backbone is not efficiency, it's loop prevention.  By requiring that all inter-area traffic traverse the backbone, OSPF prevents routing loops.  OSPF uses the SPF algorithm inside an area, but it uses a distance vector algorithm for inter-area routing.

Comment: thanks for your reply - do you really mean that traffic from area2 to area3 will actually transit through area0 instead of area1 rendering the 1Gb link unused ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: even if R1 receives both Type3 LSA (area3) from R2 through area0 and area1 - it will still send traffic via Area0 to reach Area3 ??

Comment: R2 won’t send type 3s to R1 because they are only sent to the backbone.

Comment: but R1 has an interface in the backbone - do you mean R2 wont send type3s to R1 via area 1 ?

Comment: Correct. R2 will not send type 3 lsa into a non-backbone area.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation but last one Ron, i really need to ask this -> see amended question q3)

Comment: @Noob, Area 1 needs a virtual link to Area 0, otherwise it will not work. All areas must touch Area 0.

Comment: R2 will send a type 3 LSA containing Area 3 routes to R1 (ignoring DRs for a moment).  R1 will run the SPF algorithm in area 0 and determine the shortest path to Area 3 is through the area 0 interface of R2.  That's what gets put into the routing table.

Comment: @RonMaupin why would Area1 need a virtual link to Area0 ? Area1 seems to be adjacent/connected to Area0 via R1 or R2.

Comment: @RonTrunk hmm perhaps you misread on q3, i am referring to how will inter-area traffic between Area1 <-> Area2 flows since they are both connected to R1, does it still need to adhere to the rule that all inter-area must go through Area0 ?

Comment: The answer is still absolutely Yes.  There is no path directly between the area 1 and2.

Comment: I mean area 2and 3. Traffic from A2 goes through A0 to get to A3. There is no path through area 1.

Comment: Is Area 1 connect to those routers? The image is unclear, and you didn't provide configurations.

Comment: [Here is an interesting question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/48468/8499) where a router can do a shortcut between non-backbone areas. Remember that OSPF (and other routing protocols) does not actually route the traffic, that is done by the routing table in the router. The routing protocol helps to fill the routing table.